# How would you go about find the values of a,b and c such that they f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 1 ?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function is:

\begin{align}
  f( x) &= \frac{a+bx}{1+cx} \\\\
\end{align}

The question also tells us that the function and both it's first and second derivatives are equal to the corresponding values of:

$$\ e^{x}$$

Would finding the values of a,b and c simply be a trial and error process?

Comment: Did you calculate the derivates ? The fact that all derivates of $e^x$ are $1$ at $x=0$ does not help to find the constants. Trial and error would not only be timeconsuming, but in general hopeless because you would need infitie many tries.

Comment: Have you written out the three equations you have?  For example, what can you deduce from the fact that $f(0)=1$?

Comment: From $f(0)=1$ just replace $x$ with $0$ to get $a=1$. Now you have only one unknown with one equation

Comment: @ Siddart Fredrick: **Hint:** $f(0)= a = 1$. Now, find $f'(0) = 1$ and $f''(0) =- 1$ to find the other two variables. You should find $b = \dfrac{1}{2}, c = - \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 1$ with $$f(x) = \frac{a+bx}{1+cx}$$ quickly leads to $a=1$ and $$f(x) = \frac{1+bx}{1+cx} = \frac{b}{c} - \frac{b-c}{c} \, \frac{1}{1+cx}.$$
Taking derivatives provides:
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{b-c}{(1+cx)^{2}} \\
f''(x) &= - \frac{2c (b-c)}{(1+cx)^{3}}.
\end{align}
Using the remaining conditions leads to $1 = b-c$ and $1 = -2c(b-c) = -2c$ which is $b = \frac{1}{2}$ and $c = - \frac{1}{2}$. The function then becomes
$$f(x) = \frac{2+x}{2-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly since $f(0)= 1 \implies a/1 = 1 \implies a=1$

Now $f'(x)= \dfrac{b(1+cx)+c(a+bx)}{(1+cx)^2} $

$f'(0) =  b+bc +ca +bc = c(2b+a)+b = 1 \implies 2cb+1+b=b(2c+1)+1=1 \implies  b(2c+1)=0$ therefore either $b=0$ or $c=-1/2$

You do the same thing for $f''(x)$

And you will find the solutions of $a,b$ and $c$ easily

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the denominator
$$
\frac{a+bx}{1+cx}=1+x+\tfrac12x^2+O(x^3)\\\iff\\ 
a+bx =(1+cx)(1+x+\tfrac12x^2+O(x^3))=1+(1+c)x+(\tfrac12+c)x^2+O(x^3)
$$
so comparing coefficients you get linear equations 
$$
a=1,\;b=1+c,\;0=\tfrac12+c\iff a=1,\;c=-\tfrac12,\;b=\tfrac12
$$